# Using NSTimer to create a countdown

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nstimer, countdown

I have a int value representing a countdown to an event (view being displayed). Currently, i do this:

```
- (void) buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(displayView) afterDelay:countdownValue];
}
```

What I would like to do is the following...

When the button is tapped, change the tint colour of my navigation bar to red, yellow, green proportionally, until the countdown expires, then display the view.

So for example if my countdown is 3 seconds, one second for each colour, if it is 5 seconds, 1.666 for each colour.

Can I use an NSTimer to schedule this?

After the view is displayed the timer would need invalidating.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float count_down = 5.0;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: count_down*(1.0/3.0) target: self
                               selector: @selector(changeToRed:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: count_down*(2.0/3.0) target: self
                               selector: @selector(changeToGreen:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: count_down target: self
                               selector: @selector(changeToBlue:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

And callbacks (do whatever you want there):

```
-(void) changeToRed:(NSTimer*) t {
    NSLog(@"red");
}

-(void) changeToGreen:(NSTimer*) t {
    NSLog(@"green");
}

-(void) changeToBlue:(NSTimer*) t {
    NSLog(@"blue");
}
```

Comment: There is a subtle benefit to the multi-timer approach (vs. a single timer that repeatedly fires).  Using this, you don't accumulate drift error.

Comment: This works for me, but there is a slight delay between clicking the button and the tint colour changing to red, is this because the first timer is firing after one second? Thanks

Comment: Yes. If you want timer to fire immediately then set first time interval to 0.